# Using Fullcalendar methods inside React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Fullcalendar events can be intercepted by handlres which were passed into object's props:

```
<FullCalendar
    eventDrop={ this.handleInternalDrop }                     
/>
```

How to use Fullcalendar methods such as getEvents()?
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of using getEvents() method:

```
export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {

  calendarRef = React.createRef()

  render() {
    return (
      <FullCalendar ref={this.calendarRef} />
    )
  }

  someMethod() {
    let calendarApi = this.calendarRef.current.getApi()
    calendarApi.getEvents()
  }

}
```